# Run a function identified by a string -> the right way

Tags: python, django, function, reference

In django apps like celery you can write a function, put it in a file (func.py) in a specific folder (myFunc). Now you can create a Object in django with a reference to this function to be run by a scheduler.

I don't want to write a new celery, I'd like to know what technique is used to accomplish a behavior like this: Running a function referenced by a string/or a CharField.

**Short example**

*Folder structure:*

```
myApp
---myFunc
-----func.py
-models.py
```

*func.py*

```
def test():
  print "foo"
```

*models.py*

```
class RunAFunction(models.Model):
  function = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

*python manage.py shell*

```
> from myApp.models import RunAFunction
> func = RunAFunction(function="test()")
> func.save()
```

Now I want to run `myFunc.func.test()` with my `RunAFunction()` class.
Please don't tell me that I need to use `eval()` ;)

Comment: What would you expect `RunAFunction(function="test(1)")` to do? How about `RunAFunction(function="test(1 + 2)")`? I don't see any way you can avoid using `eval` here.

Comment: And how has your code extracted `func.test` from the string `test`? How do you know it doesn't refer to `foo.test`?

Comment: @Eric: FWIW, Celery expects you to specify arguments separately, and to only use arguments that can be pickled at that. Only the module + function reference is specified as a string.

Comment: @Eric this is some django specific stuff. The RunAFunction class is simply a object (dict like) which holds the string "pointing" to my function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Split the string on the last `.` to get a module and function name, then use [`importlib`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html) and [`getattr()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) to get the object:

```
import importlib
modulename, funcname = string.rsplit('.', 1)

module = importlib.import_module(modulename)
function = getattr(module, funcname)

result = function()
```

So if `string = 'myApp.myFunc.test'`, then the above code splits that to `'modulename = 'myApp.myFunc'` and `funcname = 'test'`, then calls `importlib.import_module('myApp.myFunc')`,  and `getattr(module, 'test')` on the result, giving you a reference to the function, that then can be called.

Comment: This is why i <3 python. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

The first step is to identify your function by name only, so "test" instead of "test()".  Then you should be able to look it up within a global namespace or other module by using something like getattr().  Once you have the function in a variable, you can put the parens on and call it.